# How do I solve $4p^{3}(1-p) = [p^{4} + 4p^{3}(1-p)][1 - p^{4} - (1-p)^{4}]$?

Tags: probability, polynomials, probability-distributions

Suppose any child is male with probability $p$ or female with probability $1 − p$, independently of other children. In a family with four children, let $A$ be the event that there is at most one girl, and
$B$ the event that there are children of both sexes. Show that there is a value of $p$, with $0 < p < 1/2$, such that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

**MY ATTEMPT**

In the first place, we get $\textbf{P}(A) = p^{4} + 4p^{3}(1-p)$ and $\textbf{P}(B) = 1 - p^{4} - (1-p)^{4}$. Finally, we have $\textbf{P}(A\cap B) = 4p^{3}(1-p)$. According to the definition of independency, we obtain the following equation to solve

\begin{align*}
4p^{3}(1-p) = [p^{4} + 4p^{3}(1-p)][1 - p^{4} - (1-p)^{4}]
\end{align*}

Wolfram gives $1$ and $0.41133$ as the reals solution, but I suspect there is another approach to the problem. Could someone provide me an answer or an alternative way to tackle this exercise? I will be grateful anyway. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but
$$
4\,{p}^{3} \left( 1-p \right) - \left( {p}^{4}+4\,{p}^{3} \left( 1-p
 \right)  \right)  \left( 1-{p}^{4}- \left( 1-p \right) ^{4} \right) = -2\,{p}^{3} \left( 3\,{p}^{3}-4\,{p}^{2}+6\,p-2 \right)  \left( p-1
 \right) ^{2}
$$
so actually it is 8th degree and I don't see how you turn the main equation of degree 3 into 2?

Comment: @Diger You are right, I got a sign wrong - so easy to do.

Comment: @Diger You still get the cubic factor on which you can use intermediate value - the idea of finding a root in a range is an indication that this might be a method to use.

Comment: As in $f(p)=3p^3-4p^2+6p-2$ and $f(0)=-2$ and $f(1/2)=3/8$ and now use IVT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use computer algebra to get all the answers:

$$\left\{0,0,0,1,1,\frac{1}{9} \left(4-\frac{38}{\sqrt[3]{9 \sqrt{681}-17}}+\sqrt[3]{9 \sqrt{681}-17}\right),\frac{4}{9}+\frac{19 \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{9 \sqrt[3]{9 \sqrt{681}-17}}-\frac{1}{18}
 \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{9 \sqrt{681}-17},\frac{4}{9}+\frac{19 \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)}{9 \sqrt[3]{9
 \sqrt{681}-17}}-\frac{1}{18} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{9 \sqrt{681}-17}\right\}$$

Why does this not suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, David. But I am afraid the author expected a "clever" solution.

Comment: Alas, I don't see a "clever" solution... and wonder why one is needed—or even *wanted*—for such a problem.

Comment: If it helps, the problem comes from a probability textbook.